# Removing UIImagePickerController from UINavigationController in a UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

This worked in iOS6, so not sure what the issue is.

inside my UINavigationController (ioNavController) I present the UIImagePickerController with the Following:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.modalInPopover = YES;
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO  completion:^{  }];
```

in my UIImagePickerControllerDelegate (which does get called)I have the Following:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    //This does not work
    [ioNavController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ /* Cleanup if Needed */ }];

    //This does not work
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ /* Cleanup if Needed */ }];

    //This does not work
    [picker removeFromParentViewController];

    // This presents a new view on the Nav Controller. It shows the new view ontop of the ImagePicker. Image Picker View does not repond to touches. 
    [ioNavController pageToSelect:0];

}
```

Comment: Have you logged ioNavController to see if it's nil? Also, when you present a view controller, you should access the one that presented it with self.presentingViewController, not parentViewController.

Comment: have you tried anything? Please, give some feedback

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate it's in the same controller that called the imagepicker? The same controller that called `presentViewController` should call the line below, and the imagepicker will be removed correctly.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //self here it's the same reference that called presentViewController
```

let me know if worked or helped.

Answer (score 0):

The UIImagePickerController will remove itself when you use this code:

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)pPicker {
[pPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completition:NULL]; }
```